# Python Loop: Having trouble making calculations as the Index progresses

Tags: python, list, loops, while-loop, data-science

I have a data-frame which has 1 column (and many rows) that contains x coordinates.  My goal is to take the the sum of the differences between each of the coordinates, as the index progresses.

For example:
(x_coordinate[1] - x_coordinate[0]) + (x_coordinate[2] - x_coordinate[1]) and so forth (through a rather large dataset).

My attempt to do this is outlined below in my code -- I essentially tried to create two progressive variables (i, k) that would align with the index of the data-frame, then store those values as variables, subtract them from one another and then add that value to a list -- then after all of the differences are placed into the list, I would take the sum of the all values in the list.

The issue is, when I run this code, it only gives me the difference of the first two indices.

Also, in case it is relevant -- the goal of obtaining this value is to use it as part of a further calculation -- calculating speed of an object.

```
    def calc_distance(dataf): 
        dataf.reset_index()
        i = 0
        k = 1
        mylist = []
        lengthDf = len(df)
        while i < lengthDf:
            val_1 = dataf.Object_Center_0.iloc[i]
            val_2 = dataf.Object_Center_0.iloc[k]
            y = val_2 - val_1
            mylist.append(y)
            distance_traveled = sum(mylist)
            k+=1
            i+=1
           return distance_traveled
    calc_distance(df)
```

below here is df.head(10) -- object_center_0 just means x coordinate in this case

```
Object_Center_0
0   542.299805
1   544.108215
2   545.300598
3   546.417053
4   546.198669
5   546.724915
6   547.037048
7   547.011963
8   547.649231
9   547.600525
```

Comment: Can you update your post with the output of `df.head(10)` please?

Comment: @Corralien sorry about that -- just updated.

Comment: `y = val_2 - val_1` should be `y = abs(val_2 - val_1)`, no ?

Comment: @Corralien in this case I don't think absolute value is necessary because we're just dealing with x values, not x and y. But I honestly could be completely wrong

Comment: I'm agree but a traveled distance should be always positive. For my answer, do you prefer I remove the `abs()` method or not?

Comment: @Corralien you can remove if you’d like. My plan on keeping the value positive was to always subtract from the higher index, ie: coordinate[1] - coordinate [0] instead of the inverse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you only get the difference between the first two coordinates is that your return statement `return distance_traveled` completes and exits your function at the very first loop in your `while` expression.. A function can only return **once**. If you properly indent your return statement so that it executes *after* the while loop has finished then it should solve your problem.

```
    def calc_distance(dataf): 
        dataf.reset_index()
        i = 0
        k = 1
        distance_traveled = 0
        lengthDf = len(df)
        while i < lengthDf:
            val_1 = dataf.Object_Center_0.iloc[i]
            val_2 = dataf.Object_Center_0.iloc[k]
            y = val_2 - val_1
            distance_traveled += y
            k+=1
            i+=1
       return distance_traveled # back one indent
    calc_distance(df)
```

With that said there is a much easier solution using pandas functionality.

```
df['diff'] = df['Object_Center_0'].diff()
df['cumdiff'] = df['Object_Center_0'].diff().cumsum()


Object_Center_0     diff     cumdiff
0   542.299805       NaN         NaN
1   544.108215  1.808410    1.808410
2   545.300598  1.192383    3.000793
3   546.417053  1.116455    4.117248
4   546.198669  -0.218384   3.898864
5   546.724915  0.526246    4.425110
6   547.037048  0.312133    4.737243
7   547.011963  -0.025085   4.712158
8   547.649231  0.637268    5.349426
9   547.600525  -0.048706   5.300720
```

You could get your single value by typing

```
df['diff'].sum()

5.300719999999956
```

One last thing to know, your reset_index expression is not altering your dataframe. To do so you would need to type `dataf.reset_index(inplace=True)`. This tells pandas to alter the original dataframe. Or you could pass the value into a new dataframe `dataf = dataf.reset_index()`.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want something like that:

```
# Cumulative distance
>>> df['Object_Center_0'].sub(df['Object_Center_0'].shift()) \
                         .cumsum().fillna(0).cumsum()

0     0.000000
1     1.808410
2     4.809203
3     8.926451
4    12.825315
5    17.250425
6    21.987668
7    26.699826
8    32.049252
9    37.349972
Name: Object_Center_0, dtype: float64
```